# Problems locating 'rows' within JavaScript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, position, row

I am finding JS arrays to be maddening, I am attempting to locate the 'row' of a passed item in a (JS) 2D array.  I would not be having these issues in other languages.  I have attempted two completely different approaches, neither of which is providing a proper result.  This is how I am creating the 2D array, and it seems to be functional:

```
var _rooms = [];

var _User = function(roomNo, name) {
  this.roomNumber = roomNo;
  this.LeaderName = name;
};

_rooms.push( new _User(1, "katy") );
_rooms.push( new _User(23, "Sara") );
```

Here is the first attempt to locate a row # of a passed 'name':

```
function findPosition(str) {
var _locater, _sought, _seeks;  
  
 for (_locater = 0; _locater < _rooms.length; _locater++) {
 _seeks = _rooms[_locater];
 _sought = _seeks.indexOf(str);     
   if (_sought >= 0) {
     return "row: " + _locater + ", col: " + _sought;
   }
 }
}

console.log(findPosition('Sara'));
//SOURCE:  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46540878/finding-row-and-column-of-a-multidimensional-array-in-javascript"
```

This throws a typeError, something like "_seeks.indexOf(str) is not a function".  Here is another attempt:

```
function indexOf2dArray(itemtofind) {
var _sought
  
_sought = [].concat.apply([], ([].concat.apply([], _rooms))).indexOf(itemtofind);
            
// return "false" if the item is not found
if (_sought === -1) { return false; }

// Use any row to get the rows' array length
// Note, this assumes the rows are arrays of the same length
numColumns = _rooms[0].length;

// row = the index in the 1d array divided by the row length (number of columns)
row = parseInt(_sought / numColumns);

// col = index modulus the number of columns
col = _sought % numColumns;

return [row, col]; 
}

console.log("Sara is located: " + indexOf2dArray("Sara"))  
console.log("katy is located: " + indexOf2dArray("katy")) 
//SOURCE:  https://lage.us/Javascript-Item-in-2d-Array-Using-indexOf.html
```

The result of this approach is "false" for each of the console.log statements.  Can anybody suggest a reliable method to locate the 'row' a searched item appears in a JavaScript 2D array...?  Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: So is your output just meant to be `0` for "katy", and `1` for "Sara"? If not what is your expected output when your call `findPosition('Sara')` for example?

Comment: What you have is not a 2d array, but a 1d array of `_User`.

Comment: @Andy yes I believe as I have it setup those should be the two 'rows' as I understand it....I would expect 'Sara' to return "1"...the 'second' row

Comment: @tromgy how am I to setup a 2D array...?  From information I have gathered in research it seems that JS arrays are 'dynamic'...and a '.push' statement is the proper (only?) way to create...other than using hard-coded data...?

Comment: Yes, you can populate the array dynamically with `push`, but you're populating it with a `_User` which is actually a function that has two properties, `roomNumber` and `name`. So are you trying to return the index (as 'row') of the `_User` matching a name substring and its room numbe (as 'column')?

Comment: OK thanks for the information, so the problem lies with the construction of the array rather than the approaches to search within it.  I appreciate your input.  Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping most of your original code you can do something like this:

```
var _rooms = [];

var _User = function (roomNo, name) {
  this.roomNumber = roomNo;
  this.LeaderName = name;
};

_rooms.push(new _User(1, 'katy'));
_rooms.push(new _User(23, 'Sara'));

function findPosition(str) {
  var _locater, _sought, _seeks;

  for (_locater = 0; _locater < _rooms.length; _locater++) {
    _seeks = _rooms[_locater]; // _seeks is a _User
    _sought = _seeks.LeaderName.indexOf(str);

    if (_sought >= 0) {
      return 'row: ' + _locater + ', col: ' + _seeks.roomNumber;
    }
  }
}

console.log(findPosition('Sara')); // prints "row: 1, col: 23"
console.log(findPosition('kat'));  // prints "row: 0, col: 1"
console.log(findPosition('Joe'));  // prints "undefined"
```

Another way could be using more "modern" JavaScript:

```
function findPosition2(str) {
  const roomIndex = _rooms.findIndex((user) => user.LeaderName.includes(str));

  if (roomIndex >= 0) {
    return `row: ${roomIndex}, col: ${_rooms[roomIndex].roomNumber}`;
  } else {
    return 'not found';
  }
}

console.log(findPosition2('Sara')); // prints "row: 1, col: 23"
console.log(findPosition2('kat'));  // prints "row: 0, col: 1"
console.log(findPosition2('Joe'));  // prints "not found"
```

Comment: Thanks again for the response, it is nice that it is inclusive of almost all of my original code...basically it was required to search for the object name ('roomNumber' or 'LeaderName')...interesting.  As with the answer given by Andy below give me some time to test it out.  I appreciate your insight and time.  Regards.

Comment: Thank you again for this response, it seems to be working fine...I get the same results as you had posted.  This will come in useful, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with other languages which I imagine have definable classes why not use [JavaScript classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

Create a `User` class, and a `Users` class which has an array you can add each user [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) to.

`Users` can have a method that locates the index of the user whose name you pass into it.

```js
class Users {

  // Add the array of users
  constructor(users) {
    this.users = users;
  }

  // Use `findIndex` to return the index
  // of the array given the `name` argument
  findPosition(name) {
    const index = this.users.findIndex(obj => {
      return obj.name === name;
    });
    return `${name} is on row ${index}`;
  }

};

class User {

  // Destructure the id and name from the user object
  constructor({ id, name }) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
}

// `Users` accepts an array of user objects
const users = new Users([
  new User({ id: 1, name: 'Katy' }),
  new User({ id: 9, name: 'Boris' }),
  new User({ id: 23, name: 'Sara' })
]);

// And now you can call the users method
// to find the index of the user in the array
console.log(users.findPosition('Boris'));
console.log(users.findPosition('Sara'));
console.log(users.findPosition('Katy'));
```

Additional documentation

- [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)
- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Thank you for your reply...let me take some time to analyze your answer and give it a try.  I appreciate your input.  Regards

Comment: Thank you for this post, I find this a useful routine.  I marked the other answer as my 'accepted' answer due to the fact it used almost exactly my original code, and avoided the usage of classes.  However I do think your answer is applicable as a perfectly fine solution as well...much appreciated!